# Get a count of how many times a term or a category is used in posts

Tags: categories, terms, sql

I need to find out the number of times a term/tag or category is used in a post in WordPress. I wrote the below SQL query.

```
SELECT t.name , count(*)FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_posts p ON p.id=tr.object_id
Where t.name='3d'
```

This gives me a count of '1011' I know this is wrong because I randomly checked the posts which I got and the term was not used. Please advice where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Aggregate functions like count and sum should be accompanied by group by. If you are not using then most probably you are not doing it right!!

Comment: I use group by for all the terms. For the sake one asking a specific question I have changed it for only one term here

Comment: If you like experiments and you got some various conditions, you might try [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121768/26350) ;-)

Comment: As-written, this is a **SQL** query question, and not *specific* to **WordPress**. "*Please edit my SQL query*" is not a good fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 2):

`Wp_Query` should be able to do this for you. Pass it the appropriate parameters, including a `tax_query`, and check `found_posts`.

```
$p = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'custcpt', // your CPT
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custtax', // your tax
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $cat->term_id, // your term ID
      )
    ), 
    'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
  )
);
echo $p->found_posts;
```

Untested, but should be close.

Comment: I have never coded in wp but I think my sql logic seem to be similar to what you have given. Pls give your opinion on my sql logic. I am trying to avoid coding in wp.

Comment: When in WordPress, avoiding WordPress is a bad idea. The database structure is complicated, especially for taxonomies, and it can change. If you use Core functions, your code will survive the change. You can use `var_dump($p->request);` to inspect the SQL for yourself.

Comment: "*Pls give your opinion on my sql logic.*" - I'm unsure why a site of **WordPress** experts would have a particular opinion on *SQL logic*?

Answer (score 0):

If the taxonomy is only attached to one post type, you can just use the `term_taxonomy.count` table column.

```
SELECT t.name , tt.count FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
Where t.name='3d'
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
SELECT t.name, count(*) FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_posts p ON p.id=tr.object_id
WHERE t.name = '3d'
```