# How can I show many posts an author has per week?

Tags: posts, wp-query, author, date, date-time

I've searched around and have had no luck or success in finding a way to show how many posts an author has made in a certain period of time (e.g. - a week)

Any ideas on how one would approach this? I just want to display the total number of posts an author has made in a given time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the date_query parameter that has been added to WP 3.7
[WP_Query#Date_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) and the [author parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters).

Combine the two parameters as you need them to query all posts an author created in a given time:

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' = -1, // get all posts
        'author' => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), // from this author ID
        'date_query' => array( // in the last week
            array( 
                'year' => date('Y'),
                'week' => date('W'),
            ),
        'fields' => 'ids' // only return an array of post IDs
    ),
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
echo count( $results ); // display the number of results
echo $results->found_posts; // display the number of results
?>
```

**Edit:** I updated this answer based on input from @birgire to behave more performant.

Comment: Nice idea, but since you are fetching all the author's posts, let's hope they aren't too many ;-) You could for example add the parameter `'fields' => 'ids'` to reduce the amount of fetched data.

Comment: ps: [here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121768/26350) an  attempt to extend the `WP_Query()` to return only the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin such as [Author Stats](http://wordpress.org/plugins/author-stats/) to pull out those statistics.

If you want something more custom you'll have to write your own widget or plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I think for my current situation I'll go with this, but eventually build out my own. Thanks