# Return only Count from a wp_query request?

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql, wpdb, count

Is it possible with the standard build-in tools in Wordpress to get `wp_query` to only return the count of an query?

Right now, I’ve a query which has several meta_queries but what the only thing I’m interested in is the actually count of the query.

I know that I can use the found_posts property but the query itself generates a big overhead by query `SELECT *` and thus returns the whole object.

I could just as easy query the DB with a custom query using `$wpdb` but I would like to utilize the build-in query system if possible..

I’ve been looking for the answer for this on SE and Google but came on empty.

If I've explained myself poorly, please let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe something like [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121768/26350) where I extend the `WP_Query` class to return only the count?

Comment: @birgire I totally forgot about your post there. I even upvoted it some stage. :-). Definitely a way to go here

Comment: thanks, I had forgotten about this myself, until now ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no build in function to achieve what you want, at least not for complicated meta queries like this. If you need to use build in functions for this, the best will be to make use of `WP_Query`.

To make the query faster and to skip the unwanted returned array of `WP_Post` properties, and because you are only interested in post count, you can use the following in your parameters in your arguments

```
'fields' => 'ids',
'no_found_rows' => true,
```

This might even be a bit faster than a custom SQL query, and the results from `WP_Query` is cached as well.

Comment: Thanks.. and yes of cause it will benefit to use the fields argument for this solution.. It dramatically increased the performance :-)

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help :-) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered and since your question was based off on using `WP_Query`, my answer is probably a long-shot but you could also try to use this:

```
wp_count_posts( $type, $perm );
```

where `$type = post_type (post, page, 'custom-post-type-slug')` and where `$perm` = To include private posts readable by the current user, set to 'readable'

I've used this in the past with great success :)

```
wp_count_posts('post')->publish -> returns only the count for published posts.
```

Comment: This works yes, but it counts all posts within a given post type within a given status. The problem is, this does not work for custom fields :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a complete example - building on Pieter's notes:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post_type_goes_here',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    )
);

if ($query->have_posts()) echo count($query->posts);
else echo "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple function that would return the posts count as well as the posts (based on @Pieter's answer)

```
function get_posts_with_count($query_args, $page, $per_page)
{
    // count posts
    $posts_query = new WP_Query(
        $query_args,
    );
    $posts_count = count($posts_query->get_posts());
    $max_pages = ceil($posts_count / $page);

    // now actually get the posts
    $query_args['posts_per_page'] = $per_page;
    $query_args['paged'] = $page;
    unset($query_args['fields']);
    $posts_query = new WP_Query(
        $query_args
    );
    $posts = $posts_query->get_posts();

    return array(
        'posts_count' => $posts_count,
        'max_pages' => $max_pages,
        'data' => $posts
    );
}
```