# Convert a WP Query into a simpler SQL query to fetch only COUNT of posts

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, sql

I have this WP Query running for each row in my admin screen for a certain post type:

```
        $entry_args = array(
            'meta_key'   => 'wp_comp_entry_competition-id',
            'meta_value' => $post_ID,
            'post_type'  => 'wp_comp_entries'
        );
        $entry_query = new WP_Query( $entry_args );
```

This WP Query fetches all entries for a competition identified by the `$post_ID`. There is **a lot of** data since a single competition will have thousands entries.

In consequence, this query repeated multiple times (for each row in an admin screen) is rather slow. Moreover, I do not need all this data. I **only want to know the number of entries** for each competition identified by `$post_ID`.

I assume that the way to fetch only the `COUNT` of entries would be changing this WP Query into a simpler, direct SQL query on WordPress database.

How can I fetch only the number of entries for each competition and not all post data associated with each entry?

**Further explanation:**

I've now tried fetching only the count of posts with these two approaches:

1) Passing `'fields' => 'ids'` to query arguments

```
        $entry_args = array(
            'meta_key'   => 'wp_comp_entry_competition-id',
            'meta_value' => $post_ID,
            'post_type'  => 'wp_comp_entries',
            'fields'     => 'ids'
        );
        $entry_query = new WP_Query( $entry_args );
```

and then using `$entry_qyery->found->posts` to get the number, and

2) Using `query_posts` like this:

```
        $entry_args = array(
            'meta_key'   => 'wp_comp_entry_competition-id',
            'meta_value' => $post_ID,
            'post_type'  => 'wp_comp_entries',
            'fields'     => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $entry_query = query_posts( $entry_args );
```

and then using `count($entry_query)` to count all fetched ids (as `query_posts` returned an array).

My first experience is that `query_posts` was much slower than `WP Query` in this case.

Comment: Did you try `'fields' => 'ids'` to return only the post IDs ? [Here's another way](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121749/count-number-of-posts-public-private-protected-by-category-name/121768#121768), *"changing this WP Query into a simpler, direct SQL query"*

Comment: @birgire I wonder what the performance effect will be if we query one post only, also just get the ID of that singular post. By default, `WP_Query` will still try to find all matching posts according to query in order to count them for pagination purposes. We can then still use `$entry_query->found_posts` to get the correct post count for the specific query ;-)

Comment: @birgire, I've now added `'fields' => 'ids',` to my WP Query argumets array. I'm still using `$entry_query->found_posts` to display the count of posts. I think that this should improve performance as only `ids` are fetched.

Comment: @PieterGoosen, are you suggesting that fetching only `ids` of selected posts with `'fields' => 'ids'` will not bring a performance improvement?

Comment: No, setting the fields parameter to just get ID's can improve performance alot. It is up to 99.9% faster than a normal query. What I was thinking is, setting the `posts_per_page` parameter to just `1` and `fields` to `ids`. This will return 1 post ID, but `$found_posts` should still return a post count of all matching posts. This is how pagination is calculated. It does not matter how many posts you query, `WP_Query` still goes through the complete db counting all matching posts and stores the post count as `$found_posts`. This is used to calculate pagination.

Comment: @PieterGoosen good question, that would at least be a clean native way of doing things ;-) But I'm not sure I understand what *"thousands entries"* mean here: is it posts entries or meta post entries or even both? And what should be counted?

Comment: In `get_posts`, this feature is disabled by passing `no_found_rows=true` to `WP_Query`, that is why `get_posts` is a bit faster as it legally breaks pagination

Comment: @birgire yes, well as I see it it is based on post count per custom field value, so that is the basis of my comments. I'm stuffed if it is anything else ;-). Lets hope for the best

Comment: You should **never ever** use `query_posts` as it reruns queries. Not only that, it breaks the main query object. Do `var_dump( $wp_query );` before and after `query_posts` and check the results. Remember, `$wp_query` holds the main query object, and many plugins and functions relies on the values stored in this object

Answer (score -2):

You can also try below code to retrieve count of rows.

```
$myquery = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  tablename WHERE ID='some-value'" );
echo  $wpdb->num_rows;
```

Let me know if you have any problem.

cheers

Comment: `SELECT *` is definitely NOT the way to go. It fetches ALL data associated with a given entry and is very bad practice.

Comment: but you wanted a simple query right?